# How can I color the cell of datagrid with excel in .net core project

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a datatable in my .net core project. I want to color certain column according to the content. I created the datatable and then parsed the data.

```
DataTable dt = new();     
dt.Columns.Add("Status");
dt.Columns.Add("Base");
dt.Columns.Add("First Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Second Date");
dt.Columns.Add("Failure Mode");

dataAll.ForEach(row =>
{
    dt.Rows.Add(
        row.status,
        row.partBase,
        row.pcaDate,
        row.icaDate,
        row.failureMode
    );
});
```

I want to change the color of the status column. For example to color this cell red if the status is equal to R. How can I color the Datatable cell.This is how I export with Excel;

```
        using XLWorkbook wb = new();
        // create data table
        DataTable dt = MapDataToExcel(response.Result.ToList());

        // add as worksheet
        wb.Worksheets.Add(dt, "Rapor");          
       
        // save it as a file then stream it to the user
        using MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        wb.SaveAs(stream);

        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Rapor.xlsx");
```

Comment: It is not clear how you are presenting the data, please include a sample of how you want the data to be presented.

Comment: Hi @Sümeyye Barut, whether the problem solved or not? If not, can you share the relates code in the view/razor page, so that we can know how you are presenting the data, directly use foreach statement to loop the DataTable and build a html table, or using some JQuery data table plugin to display the data, it is easier for us to help you fix it.

Comment: Hello, it hasn't solved. I export datatable with excel using XLWORKBOOK. I have added related code main side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 2; i < dataCount; i++)
            {
               

                foreach (var item in wb.Worksheets)
                {   
                    var objPage2 = item.Cell(i, 1).GetString();
                    if (objPage2 == "R") { item.Cell(i, 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Red; }
                    if (objPage2 == "G") { item.Cell(i, 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Green; }
                    if (objPage2 == "Y") { item.Cell(i, 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Yellow; }

                }
            }
```

Check the value of the specific column and color them depending on value

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that the status field is a boolen value. You can include this method in your code fragment and change the condition according to your own definition.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    bool status = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells["Status"].Value);
    if (status)
    {
       e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else
    {
       e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: it is not a boolean value and I don't use windows form so I can't use using  keyword with windows form in .net core

Comment: Where you are viewing DataTable

Comment: When click the buttton, I export Datatable with excel

Comment: I think you are writing the DataTable data to an Excel worksheet. You can loop through the rows of this worksheet with a loop and give color.` foreach (ExcelRow row in worksheet.Rows)
    {
        if (row["Status"].Value == "R") row.BackColor = Color.Red;     
    }`

Comment: it does't work. I can't use color keyword and cant invoke the worksheet.rows